# Modify list edit and display forms using InfoPath

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-designer

From SharePoint Designer it is possible to modify the edit and display list forms.

From the ribbon in ListSettings tab select **Design Forms In InfoPath** and choose the content type you want to modify forms for. InfoPath will open with a generated form and the form can be modified.

My question is when you publish the form from InfoPath to a SharePoint List is it posible to export the list and import it to list in SharePoint Foundation or are the forms dependent on InfoPath ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you design the form with InfoPath, it will appear to be an ASPX page, but the page contains an InfoPathForm webpart.

Therefore, when you run this on SharePoint foundation you will get a webpart missing error. Since the Infopath webpart is only included in the Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need SharePoint Enterprise.